# Initialize Lua array in a function and use it outside. I do not get it

Tags: arrays, lua, garrys-mod

```
playerInjuries = {}

function OnPlayerTakeDamage(ply, dmginfo)
    if ply:IsPlayer() and dmginfo:IsDamageType(DMG_BULLET) then
        local hitgroup = ply:LastHitGroup()
        
        local injuryType = ""
        local injuryDescription = ""
        
        if hitgroup == HITGROUP_LEFTARM then
            local randomNum = RandomNumber(1, 100)
            if randomNum >= 75 then
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Links"][1]
            elseif randomNum <= 75 and randomNum >= 85 then
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Links"][2]
            elseif randomNum <= 85 and randomNum >= 95 then
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Links"][3]
            else
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Links"][4]
            end
        elseif hitgroup == HITGROUP_RIGHTARM then
            local randomNum = RandomNumber(1, 100)
            if randomNum >= 75 then
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Rechts"][1]
            elseif randomNum <= 75 and randomNum >= 85 then
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Rechts"][2]
            elseif randomNum <= 85 and randomNum >= 95 then
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Rechts"][3]
            else
                injuryType = injuries["Arm Rechts"][4]
            end
        elseif hitgroup == HITGROUP_LEFTLEG then
            local randomNum = RandomNumber(1, 100)
            if randomNum >= 75 then
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Links"][1]
            elseif randomNum <= 75 and randomNum >= 85 then
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Links"][2]
            elseif randomNum <= 85 and randomNum >= 95 then
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Links"][3]
            else
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Links"][4]
            end
        elseif hitgroup == HITGROUP_RIGHTLEG then
            local randomNum = RandomNumber(1, 100)
            if randomNum >= 75 then
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Rechts"][1]
            elseif randomNum <= 75 and randomNum >= 85 then
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Rechts"][2]
            elseif randomNum <= 85 and randomNum >= 95 then
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Rechts"][3]
            else
                injuryType = injuries["Bein Rechts"][4]
            end
        elseif hitgroup == HITGROUP_CHEST or hitgroup == HITGROUP_GENERIC then
            
        elseif hitgroup == HITGROUP_HEAD then
        
        end
        
        if injuryType ~= "" then
           if not playerInjuries[ply] then
            playerInjuries[ply] = {}
            end

            table.insert(playerInjuries[ply], injuryType)

            test(ply, injuryType)
        end
    end
end

function test(ply, injuryType)
    ply:ChatPrint(injuryType)
    ply:ChatPrint("Spielerverletzungen: " .. table.concat(playerInjuries[ply], ", "))
end
```

outside the OnPlayerTakeDamage function the player Injuries or players Injuries[ply] array is nil and I don't understand why or how to fix this.

Everything except the array works.If it's helpful. The code is for the game Garry's mod

The array playerInjuries[ply] should have a table for each player that contains all injuries of the respective player.

Comment: Worth noting, `ply` also acts as a table, and data can be written directly to it. eg. `ply.playerInjuries = ply.playerInjuries or {}`

Answer (score 0):

> outside the OnPlayerTakeDamage function the player Injuries or players Injuries[ply] array is nil

Before worrying about `playerInjuries[ply]`, make sure that `playerInjuries` isn't `nil` in `test()` by printing it. I suspect `playerInjuries` is never `nil` in your program, though you may have some code you didn't share that sets it to `nil`.

Make sure `test()` is getting called at all, and only by the one spot you shared.

Once you made sure `playerInjuries` is never `nil` inside `test`, you can add `for k, v in pairs(playerInjuries) do print(k, v) end` to print the keys and values in it.

Comment: test() is not called anywhere else in my code and I actually don't have a function that sets playerInjuries to nil. Before test() is called, the playerInjuries variable is always initialized, but can never be used outside of its own function. And that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @Deadshot "but can never be used outside of its own function" in the code you shared the variable is global though, so it doesn't belong to any function. Make sure that it's actually global by adding `print(playerInjuries)` in `test()`, and letting `test()` get called somehow. After that, continue with what my answer suggested.

Comment: ok I can use the array outside the function. But I have another question. When I try to call `for i, path in pairs(playerInjuries[ply]) do` I get nil. Do you know why?

Comment: @Deadshot As general advice, when in doubt: print everything. In this case you didn't tell me what `print(playerInjuries[ply])` prints. Whatever followup question you ask me is pretty much always going to be answered with "print everything". :)